# How to merge many MDBs?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have many MDBs files with the same structure and two tables each.

Is there any way how to merge this bases in huge one?

I try to use special utilit ["Simple MDB Merge"](http://simple-mdb-merge.findmysoft.com/), but it doesn't see mdb files on my computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open up one of the MDBs, and import tables into it from all the other MDBs. If there are really a lot of MDBs and it would be impractical to do it by hand, you can write some VBA code to open each MDB in turn and copy over the tables into your destination MDB. Look up the Access and DAO references for working with databases and tables.

Comment: I open MDB file in the Access - one table appear (for example, call it 'tab'). Then select 'Import Access data base', select there table and it appears as 'tab1'. I can't understand how to merge 'tab' and 'tab1'. Can u explain?

Comment: @nuT707 - sure. I'm assuming `tab` and `tab1` have the same columns. If so you can just use an `insert` query to insert all rows from `tab1` into `tab`. If you need to you can also add in another column into `tab` to indicate which table each row originally came from--to disambiguate.